# MinionPro: spacing between f followed by quotes

Tags: fonts, minionpro

Is it just me, or is the spacing between the letter 'f' and the following quotation marks incredibly tight in `MinionPro`? I am already using the `loosequotes` option, but as far as I can tell, that only increases the distance of the quotes from the text inside them.

## Problem:

[image: Problem]

Look at the difference in spacing between Minion Pro, Computer Modern and Palatino, and also look at how much better the spacing looks between the letter 'e' and quotation marks. The spacing looks way too tight for my taste.

Assuming that I am not absolutely insane and that other people notice the issue as well, is there an easy way to fix this?

---

I also have sample text for all letters of the (English) alphabet followed by quotation marks, but I think the letter 'f' looks the worst.

[image: Alphabet output]

## MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[loosequotes]{MinionPro}

\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmr} % Computer Modern | #yolo
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{ppl} % Palatino        | #yolo

\usepackage{parskip}

\newcommand*{\sometextsingle}{Issue of `Minion Pro' font}
\newcommand*{\sometextdouble}{Issue of ``Minion Pro'' font}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
Minion Pro               & \sometextsingle          & \sometextdouble\\
\texttt{Computer Modern} & \texttt{\sometextsingle} & \texttt{\sometextdouble}\\
\textsf{Palatino}        & \textsf{\sometextsingle} & \textsf{\sometextdouble}
\end{tabular}

\renewcommand*{\sometextsingle}{Issue of the `Minion Pro' font}
\renewcommand*{\sometextdouble}{Issue of the ``Minion Pro'' font}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
Minion Pro               & \sometextsingle          & \sometextdouble\\
\texttt{Computer Modern} & \texttt{\sometextsingle} & \texttt{\sometextdouble}\\
\textsf{Palatino}        & \textsf{\sometextsingle} & \textsf{\sometextdouble}\\
\end{tabular}
 
\vspace{0.5cm}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
a `Minion Pro' & A `Minion Pro'\\
b `Minion Pro' & B `Minion Pro'\\
c `Minion Pro' & C `Minion Pro'\\
d `Minion Pro' & D `Minion Pro'\\
e `Minion Pro' & E `Minion Pro'\\
f `Minion Pro' & F `Minion Pro'\\
g `Minion Pro' & G `Minion Pro'\\
h `Minion Pro' & H `Minion Pro'\\
i `Minion Pro' & I `Minion Pro'\\
j `Minion Pro' & J `Minion Pro'\\
k `Minion Pro' & K `Minion Pro'\\
l `Minion Pro' & L `Minion Pro'\\
m `Minion Pro' & M `Minion Pro'\\
n `Minion Pro' & N `Minion Pro'\\
o `Minion Pro' & O `Minion Pro'\\
p `Minion Pro' & P `Minion Pro'\\
q `Minion Pro' & Q `Minion Pro'\\
r `Minion Pro' & R `Minion Pro'\\
s `Minion Pro' & S `Minion Pro'\\
t `Minion Pro' & T `Minion Pro'\\
u `Minion Pro' & U `Minion Pro'\\
v `Minion Pro' & V `Minion Pro'\\
w `Minion Pro' & W `Minion Pro'\\
x `Minion Pro' & X `Minion Pro'\\
y `Minion Pro' & Y `Minion Pro'\\
z `Minion Pro' & Z `Minion Pro'\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have to report this to the editors of this font. This looks really very narrow. Easiest way in order to fix this would be to search for `f '` and replace it by `f\kern x.xpt'`. See here about the topic of kerning adjustment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10455

Comment: the "f" is almost always wider than its nominal width; that is why ligatures were created, and kerns were developed for metal type, and the *italic correction* for tex.  take a look at this question for an explanation: [How does italic correction work?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/93961/579)

Comment: @LaRiFaRi With egreg's answer and Barbara's comment about italic correction, do you think that the issue is something I should still report? How would I go about doing that? Thank you.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for the interesting link. egreg's answer resolves the issue by adding italic correction manually.

Comment: @sudosensei You should still report it to the font creators/maintainers so that they may add a permanent fix.

Comment: @Sverre I would love to do that, but I do not know how to proceed. I can't find any contact information on the Minion Pro Adobe page. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The letter “f” extends past its bounding box; this is usually not a problem for normal text; in this case, however, the space between “f” and the left quote seems too small for making the quote prominent.

The protrusion is not as big in Computer Modern and is absent in Palatino.

Solution: add the italic correction (`\/` after the letter 'f').

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}

\begin{document}

\begingroup % show the bounding boxes
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.1pt}
\fbox{f} \fbox{`}\endgroup

f `Minion'

f\/ `Minion'
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: I don't have the fonts for `pdflatex`, so I used XeLaTeX, but it should be the same.

Comment: That does it! Thank you! I hope you don't mind, but I took the liberty of clarifying how italic correction is added – I had no idea what changed initially. `:-)`