# Do better Italics correction in textit with maths

Tags: blackboard, italic-correction, amsfonts

The code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\textit{Given a collection \(M\) of \(\mathbb{S}\)-terrible $n$-beautiful gizmos ...}
\end{document}enter code here
```

produces too much space in `\(M\) of` and too little space in `of \(\mathbb{S}\)`:

[image]
I believe the latter issue can be dealt with by saying `of\/ \(\mathbb{S}\)`. What's the standard way to deal with the former one?

Comment: latex has made some things (more) automatic in the transition between italic and uptight, but this doesn't carry over to math.  it's a limitation of the underlying engine.  try this with (plain) tex: `\it Given a collection $M$ of $\rm S$-terrible $n$-beautiful gizmos \dots \bye`.

Comment: There are some aesthetic considerations that may need manual application when using italic correction. See [How does italic correction work?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/93961/5764)

Comment: @LeonMeier -- sadly, i don't know of any package that provides the desired facility.  (that's not to say that none exist.)  it's not an easy problem.

Answer (score 3):

I have changed your source with this below:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsfonts, mathtools}
\begin{document}
\textit{Given a collection $M$ \!of $\mathbb{S}$--terrible $n$--beautiful gizmos \ldots}
\end{document}
```

I have add only `\!`. What do you think? Now work correctly.

[image]

Comment: The mathtools package is an extension package to amsmath. I have add only to have not problem during the compliation with Papeeria. On this PC I have not MikTeX.

Comment: May I suggest, instead, `\textit{Given a collection $M\!$ of $\,\mathbb{S}$\nobreakdash-terrible $n$\nobreakdash-beautiful gizmos \ldots}`?

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti -- i agree with the positioning of the negative space within the math.  but wouldn't an italic correction, `\/` after the `f` be more in keeping with the latex style?

Comment: @barbarabeeton: good point!