# How do I disable ligatures?

Tags: ligatures

I am writing my dissertation in LaTeX I am faced with this odd situation that if 'f' character has another character (f, i or l) next to it, it sticks the two together as can be noted below. This makes the two 'f' look different.

[image: example of 2 ligated Fs in "Different"]

How can I disable this?

Comment: This is called *ligature*. It is a common procedure. Don't worry and be happy. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature

Comment: @Sigur However this looks rather odd given that it is part of the title of my dissertation. Can be this be turned off in some way?

Comment: You can probably see a similar effect if you write `fish` or `flat` or `affiche`.

Comment: If you really want (I don't recommend) you can type `Di{f}{f}erent`

Comment: if you look at any printed works for the last few hundred years you will see ff ligatures, it would look more odd if you force the separate f

Comment: Even though you might be sceptical about the ff ligature I think with a bold Latin/Computer moden you definitely want the fi ligature.

Comment: If you don't like ligatures use Word ;-)

Comment: Don't suppress ligatures! It is a feature of superior typography.

Comment: If the problem is only that it's in the title, have you considered a different font for your title, such as small caps? (`\textsc{Different ...}`)

Comment: Somehow what the other comments fail to acknowledge is that this is a *terrible* ligature. The default font unfortunately has these flaws. A fix is therefore to use a better font.

Comment: @AlexG It's not very convincing if you just keep repeating that it's "superior" without an argument (or at least a reference/link to one). OP is not going to buy it, especially because the ligature in her example looks horrible.

Comment: @Federico Others did already in the meantime, so I didn't want to add redundancy. OP, was worried initially just because she obviously didn't know about ligature. (She could't identify is as such.) Now that she knows that it is common practise in typesetting, it may look less odd in her eyes.

Comment: @AlexG one who oppresses ligatures, also eats small children and ducks...especially ducks.

Comment: @naphaneal I completely agree with you.

Comment: Why was the question changed? It invalidates the first comment.

Comment: Ligatures are bad because they mess up the text if somebody is copy-pasting from the pdf document.

Comment: @Sigur `{f}{f}` didn't work to turn off ligature. `f\/f` did.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Ligatures are generally considered a good thing, but if you really want to disable them and are using pdfLaTeX (or LuaLaTeX<sup>†</sup>), the [`microtype`](https://ctan.org/pkg/microtype) package can do this for you.
If you load this package and add `\DisableLigatures{encoding = *, family = * }` to your preamble, all ligatures will disappear from your output.

Here's an example (pdfLaTeX only):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{microtype}
\DisableLigatures{encoding = *, family = *}
% \DisableLigatures[f]{encoding = *, family = *} %% <- only disables f-ligatures

\begin{document}

Different -- without ligatures!

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the double hyphen (`--`), which is normally typeset as a single en dash, is also treated as a ligature by TeX and that this is suppressed as well.  The standard set of ligatures that TeX recognises consists of:

```
Actual ligatures: ff → ﬀ     fi → ﬁ     fl → ﬂ     ffi → ﬃ    ffl → ﬄ
"Fake" ligatures: -- → –    --- → —     `` → “      ’’ → ”      !` → ¡     ?` → ¿
```

You can use `\DisableLigatures[f]{encoding = *, family = * }` to only disable ligatures that start with the letter `f` (i.e., the entire top row).

The `microtype` package actually does a lot more than this. It implements a number of micro-typographical features that generally improve the layout of your paragraphs. (See the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/microtype/microtype.pdf) for more information.)

---

<sup>†</sup>To make this work with LuaLaTeX you need to also use the `fontspec` package and supply the `Renderer=Basic` option while loading your font. For LuaLaTeX, [Mico's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/439659/156366) is therefore preferable.

Comment: Can you turn them back on again, after the title?

Comment: No, I'm afraid not. You could with @Mico's answer though, but you'd have to switch to LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX for that. For example, `{\addfontfeature{Ligatures=NoCommon}off} off` prints "off" twice: once without ligatures and once with.

Comment: `--` is not a ligature; it's a digraph comprised of two ASCII characters representing the non-ASCII en dash.

Comment: @chepner It is a ligature as far as TeX is considered. That is, this is how it is coded. Of course, you are correct in the non-TeXnical sense of 'ligature'.

Comment: @chepner You're right, I've modified my answer to clarify this.

Comment: Doesn't work at all.

Comment: @vonbrand: I just tested this (using TeXLive 2020, fully updated) and it still works for me. You must be setting up your document differently in some way.

Comment: I tried adding it in a (LyX) document, and get `! pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable `, probably I need to change font?

Comment: @Matifou, you can also try adding `expansion=false` as an option when loading `microtype`. Loading the package will by default also turn on character protrusion (allowing characters to protrude slightly into the margin to improve the visual appeal of your paragraphs) and font expansion (allowing characters to be stretched/shrunk a little when laying out paragraphs), and the latter only works for scalable fonts. These are in fact the main purpose of the package.

Comment: I had the same error as @Matifou. Removing `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` solved the problem.

Answer (score 20):

From [Buttericks Practical Typography](https://practicaltypography.com/ligatures.html):

> *Lig­a­tures* were in­vented to solve a prac­ti­cal type­set­ting prob­lem. In the days of metal fonts, cer­tain char­ac­ters had fea­tures that phys­i­cally col­lided with other char­ac­ters. To fix this, font mak­ers in­cluded lig­a­tures with their fonts, which com­bined the trou­ble­some let­ters into one piece of type.

These are the examples:

[image]

However, not all fonts have the **ff** ligature with both letters fused, so if you do not like them, the best that you can do is to choose another font.
In the [Latex font catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/seriffonts.html) every font has a section *Ligatures and German double s*, where you can see how they will be displayed.

For instance:

[Bookman](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/bookman/):

[image]

[Cochineal](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/cochineal/):

[image]

[Garamond](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/garamond/):

[image]

[Didot](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/gfsdidot/):

[image]

**Font without ligatures**:

[New TXTT](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/newtxtt/):

[image]

[Letter Gothic](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/lettergothic/)

[image]

**Note**: I do not know an easy way to find a font without ligatures, we open it and look for absence of the Ligature section.

Comment: Maybe you can add a comparison of ligature vs no ligature in Computer/Latin modern (bold/normal). For bold I think the fi ligature is necessary, but the ff might be more debatable.

Answer (score 18):

Ligatures are a feature of superior typography!

However, there are cases where good typography indeed calls for suppressing them, especially in German texts: at word-seams (German: Wortfuge).

With package `babel` and the `ngerman` option, ligatures are suppressed using `"|`

For example `Auf"|lage`, `auf"|finden`, `auf"|fangen`, `schlaf"|los`.

As stated in Mico's comment a number of English words also call for suppressing f ligatures. Here, this is accomplished through `\/`:

`shelf\/ful`, `self\/less`, `half\/line`, ...

---

But again, keep ligatures in `different`, `affordable` etc.

Comment: +1. I fully agree with you that (a) ligatures are a feature of superior typography and (b) there are cases when ligatures should be suppressed. However, the OP's example -- the word "different" -- is not among these cases; it may be worth stating this fact explicitly, lest there be any confusion among readers as to whether the `ff` ligature in `different` is somehow inappropriate. Incidentally, if you wanted to give examples of English language words for which f-ligatures should be suppressed, you could mention shelfful, selfless, halfline, wolffish (yes, there is such a thing), and chaffinch.

Comment: Thank you. I edited the answer. Is `\/` the correct means of suppressing ligatures?

Comment: Indeed, `\/` is one possible way for suppressing ligatures, but it's not necessarily the best way. Other methods are inserting `\kern0pt` or `{}`. (However, the `{}`method does not work under Lua(La)TeX, and it doesn't even work always under pdf(La)TeX.) Aside: All of these methods have as a side-effect that hyphenation is no longer possible at the indicated ligature suppression points. A package (LuaLaTeX-only) that performs selective ligature suppression is [selnolig](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/selnolig). Full disclosure: I'm the main author and maintainer of this package.

Comment: Invented technical words may need a ligature suppressed: pdfid meaning the id number of a pdf tends to be mispronounced pee dee fid, without `pdf\/id`.

Answer (score 10):

If you absolutely must suppress ligatures (not a good idea, but since you insist...) and if you happen to use either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX to compile your LaTeX document, you could achieve your typesetting objective by specifying the option `Ligatures=NoCommon` while executing `\setmainfont`, `\setsansfont`, etc. Alternatively, run `\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=NoCommon}` before running `\setmainfont` and `\setsansfont`.

Aside: This method will not keep `--` and `---` from being made into en-dashes and em-dashes, respectively.

[image]

A final comment: Do learn not to only tolerate, but to actually appreciate and like typographic ligatures. They're your friends -- typographically speaking.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=NoCommon}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setsansfont{Myriad Pro}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\newcommand\blurb{off fit fly office baffle}
\begin{document}
\blurb

\textbf{\blurb}

\sffamily
\blurb

\textbf{\blurb}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Much as I like the visual aspect of ligatures, there aren't your friend in the digital world. My thesis was set in (pdf)LaTeX with default ligatures. But use is inconsistent. The 'ff' ligature is used in headings but not the ToC. Copying/exporting to plain-text (for ML/AI use) the monospaced fonts used in output generally have no ligature glyph. Thus 'office' exports as 'oce' and 'proffessor' as 'proessor'. So, in today's world, unless only targetting paper or un-remediated use. So if using plain-text from LaTeX PDFs for AI/ML, take care!

Comment: @mwra - I suppose all kinds of things -- and not just ligatures -- are quaint and maybe even obsolete "in the digital world". However, assuming one has compiled a LaTeX document properly, i.e., *not* via the hide-bound tex-dvi-ps-pdf route, I don't agree with your claim that one cannot successfully copy and paste text that contains ligated letters from a pdf file to a plain-text file, say, for AI/ML purposes. For sure, I do such copy and paste operations regularly (from LaTeX documents I've compiled myself), and I have yet to encounter this problem. Maybe I'm just lucky...

Comment: I think you are 'just lucky'. Most LaTeX users I encountered in recent post-grad/doc work had little expertise/interest in LaTeX being something they are made to use, i.e. it working properly is up to *someone else*. Working with text stripped for PDFs, it is a problem (discussing data cleaning seems taboo as so many people don't!). AFACT, problem arises as PDF was originally for digitally capturing and preserving print [sic] layout.  Providing clean un-styled text likely wasn't even thought about - I don't it anywahererecall in Adobe Acrobat certification training.

Comment: @mwra I don't recommend spelling professor as proffessor, ligatures or not ^^  Beyond that, your problem is broader than ligatures: you're looking for tagged PDFs, which no LaTeX compiler currently has proper support for, unfortunately https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261537/a-guide-on-how-to-produce-accessible-pdf-files

Comment: @Clément. Hah, a typo—sadly one of several I can't now fix (dyslexia/dyspraxia are a daily issue). But whilst 'proffessor' is —in English—a typo it nonetheless still shows the ligature issue, which was the main point in case you misunderstood the comment. I've since found another nasty disconnect.  If I take heading from the ToC, the ToC listings don't use ligatures whilst the body copy heading do. More inconsistency.  Then again, PDFs & Postscript were intended as accurate digital *paper*, not digital *text*.

Answer (score 0):

For those who just want to disable only one place (e.g. inside some links). You can try to use `T\/h`, `f\/i`, which will avoid combining the characters together.

Comment: For technical detail: `\/` is called italic correction. [How does italic correction work? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93961/how-does-italic-correction-work)