# How can I print three greater-than symbols after each other (>>>)?

Tags: symbols, amssymb, substitution

I am using `\texttt` to write my code snippets in Courier font including `\texttt{>>>}`. If I compile, this is substituted to ». How can I prevent that from happening?

- I am unable to escape with `\texttt{\>\>\>}`.
- I do not want to use `\ggg` of the amssymb package since that looks slightly different.
- If possible I would also like to avoid using `\verb||`.

Comment: Try `{{>}{>}{>}}`.  The addition of groups will prevent each from seeing the others, and therefore should prevent (for lack of a better word) the ligature from forming.

Comment: `\texttt{>\kern0pt>\kern0pt>}` should do the trick. (`\texttt{>\/>\/>}` often works too if your font isn't slanted/italic)

Comment: Somewhat related: [How do I disable ligatures? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/439651/how-do-i-disable-ligatures)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This happens when you use the T1 encoding.

You can disable the ligature that maps `>>` to `»` with `microtype`. I also removed the ligature from `<<` to `«` for symmetry. The first line shows that the ligatures are not suppressed altogether, but only when using the monospaced font.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{microtype}

\DisableLigatures[<,>]{encoding=T1,family=tt*}

\begin{document}

<<This is quoted>>

\texttt{>>>}

\texttt{<<<}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

The addition of a group around the central `>` will prevent each from seeing the others, and therefore should prevent (for lack of a better word) the ligature from forming.

Note: See comments to this answer, which are very illuminating, which explains why this technique will work in pdflatex but not lualatex!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\begin{document}
\texttt{>{>}> versus >>>}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This only works as long as `>{>}>` is not considered for hyphenation, which might or might not be the case. I think in `\texttt` it is actually safe, because by default LaTeX disables hyphenation for this family.  Note that TeX merely *considering* the compound for hyphenation is already enough to break this mechanism, it doesn't have to be actually hyphenated.

Comment: @HenriMenke I am not sure I understand your point. Are you saying for (other than texttt) that this answer could fail, or only that it could get hyphenated, or that, if hyphenated, it could fail?

Comment: When TeX hyphenates words, it breaks all ligatures, scans for hyphenation points and then reinserts the ligatures. At that point, however, the braces are no longer present because they don't create a node, so TeX will reinsert a previously suppressed ligature. For this it is sufficient that TeX *considers* the word for hyphenation, it doesn't actually have to hyphenate it. In `\texttt` this problem will not show up as long as hyphenation is disabled (the default). If you want to make really sure that TeX never ligatures this thing, you have to write `>\kern0pt>\kern0pt>`.

Comment: @HenriMenke Thank you for that informative reply.  But then why, in my MWE, if I change `\texttt` to `\textit`, and add enough leading verbiage to force a line break in the paragraph, does the problem not arise?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes In addition to forcing a line break, you actually need a paragraph which gets hyphenated, otherwise TeX never runs the second line breaking pass where it considers word for hyphenation. I also think this only triggers in words which are considered for hyphenation in the sense that there is at least one potential hyphenation point identified in the word, so `>>>` should be safe. (Of course breaking ligatures like this doesn't work in LuaTeX at all)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes In pdflatex with `T1` encoding, the `\lccode` of `>` is `0`, so this doesn't happen for `>>` and `>{>}` can be used.  The point that this method does not work in luatex, should be emphasised.