# Strings contain fi misparsed in resume parsers

Tags: fonts, pdf, copy-paste

I am having a consistent bug with resume parsers and was wondering if anybody has suggestions

Any word that has the substring "fi" essentially removes the substring

Do you guys have any suggestions to ensure that everything I type is parsed accurately?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please give an example of a resume parser program. Please also state how the document that contains "fi" substrings is compiled. Ideally, you'd provide (a) a complete (but minimal) test document that contains at least one "fi"-substring and (b) sufficient information about the resume-parsing program to allow others to replicate the issue you wish to fix.

Comment: you give no indication of the code you are using but tag the question overleaf, if it is a tex question it will apply whatever system you use and be unrelated to overleaf. Unless you are asking about the overleaf editor rather than tex output

Comment: You can try some of the solutions in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/439651/how-do-i-disable-ligatures to make sure `f` and `i` are rendered as two separate letters instead of the `ﬁ` ligature.