# Runaway-argument error message when line break occurs inside argument of a macro

Tags: macros, arguments

I'm having trouble with my \newcommand when I have a linebreak inside the argument, it is defined as:

```
\documentclass{report}
\newcommand{\noblablabla}[2]{\textbf{#1}-#2}
\begin{document}

\noblablabla{aaaabbbb}{xxxx} % this is OK

\noblablabla{aaaa

 bbbb}{xxxx} 
\end{document}
```

The first call is OK, the second call gives me the Runaway argument error and the result is the following:

```
 bbbb}{xxxx} 
 % ^^ up here "Runaway argument"
```

[image: with error]

When I espected some thing like

[image: expectation]

Comment: `\textbf` forwards its argument to `\text@command`, which is declared as a short macro, so it can't contain a `\par` in its argument. You can circumvent this by using `\endgraf` instead of the two consecutive newlines, but I don't think it is a good idea and you should change your macro if you want to have a newline there.

Comment: And welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Thanks Skillmon, kind of you.
I am not used to 'low level' tricks like you are commenting.
How should I change my macro to get the right result? Can you gime some directions to undestand its limitations? How can I start to study it?

Comment: Change `\textbf{#1}` to `{\bfseries #1}`. Why? `\bfseries` can handle paragraph breaks -- recall that an all-blank input line generates a paragraph break -- in its scope, whereas `\textbf` can not.

Comment: Nice, guys, got it!
Thanks!

Comment: @LucasT important to note is that there is a slight difference in `{<fontswitch> #1}` to `<textcommand>{#1}`, the former doesn't apply any italic correction whereas the latter would (though this shouldn't be an issue for `\textbf`, it could for `\textit`).

Comment: @Skillmon can be solved by `{\itshape #1\/}`? Not sure, so I am not modifying the answer... is italic correction dependent on the current font, the next font or both?

Comment: @Rmano LaTeX goes to some length to apply it correctly (and I don't know the entire code it runs to determine the italic correction), but with normal text `\/` should be correct (it's dependent on the current font and the last symbol in `#1` and might be dependent on the next symbol in the following text).

Comment: @LucasT, if the answer helped you, please consider accepting it: https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As suggested in comments, `\textbf` is designed for short things --- not paragraphs. You can just change to a font-selection command:

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\newcommand{\noblablabla}[2]{{\bfseries #1\/}-#2}
\begin{document}

\noblablabla{aaaabbbb}{xxxx} % this is OK

\noblablabla{aaaa

 bbbb}{xxxx} 
 % no more "Runaway argument"
\end{document}
```

...look carefully at the `{` placement ;-).

The `\/` will perform [*italic correction*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93961/how-does-italic-correction-work) if necessary (shouldn't be necessary with a bold typeface, but it is font-dependent); thanks to [@Skillmon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/508773/runaway-argument-error-message-when-line-break-occurs-inside-argument-of-a-macro?noredirect=1#comment1286739_508773) for pointing it out.

[image: output of the code snippet]

Comment: @Mico sorry, I posted the answer before seeing your comment...

Comment: No worries! Anyway, providing a standalone answer is considered better form anyway.

Answer (score 3):

When (La)TeX reads and tokenizes input under standard catcode-régime with standard-value for the integer-parameter `\endlinechar`, two consecutive endline-characters—in the .tex-input file they yield an empty line—get tokenized as the token `\par` which usually serves for ending the current paragraph (and having (La)TeX start a new paragraph in case material which triggers switching to horizontal mode follows).

In (La)TeX macros come in two flavours:

1. Macros where the token `\par` is allowed in the arguments. These are so-called "long macros" because when you wish to define such a macro by means of TeX primitives like `\def` or `\edef` or `\gdef` or `\xdef`, you need to add the prefix `\long` to the definition-primitive in use.
2. Macros where the token `\par` is not allowed in the arguments. Many people call them "short macros" because when defining them you omit the `\long`-prefix. When an argument of a short macro contains the token `\par`, then you get an error-message about "Runaway argument?... Paragraph ended before ... was complete".

`\textbf` is defined to call such a such a "short" macro whose name is `\text@command`, and to pass its argument as argument to that macro. Therefore the error message. You can easily circumvent that message by not having the token `\par` within the argument and instead having, e.g., the token sequence `\csname par\endcsname` in the argument, or the token `\myparcopy` after `\let\myparcopy=\par`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\newcommand{\noblablabla}[2]{\textbf{#1}-#2}
\begin{document}

\noblablabla{aaaabbbb}{xxxx} % this is OK

\noblablabla{aaaa\csname par\endcsname bbbb}{xxxx} 
\end{document}



\documentclass{report}
\newcommand\myparcopy{}%
\newcommand{\noblablabla}[2]{\textbf{#1}-#2}
\begin{document}

\noblablabla{aaaabbbb}{xxxx} % this is OK

\let\myparcopy=\par
\noblablabla{aaaa\myparcopy bbbb}{xxxx} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: LaTeX and Plain already have a `\myparcopy` under the name `\endgraf`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik The reason why I didn't suggest `\endgraf` is: `\endgraf` is intended to be a copy of the primitive `\par` while the `\long`-mechanism aims at the control word token token `\par` regardless its meaning. So `\endgraf` as `\parcopy` is possible only as long as `\par` still has the meaning of the primitive. You can redefine `\par`, e.g., to expand to "I should have my socks stuffed, but my UNIVAC has no app for that" and with a macro not defined in terms of `\long` you still get runaway argument errors in case of one of its arguments containing the token `\par`.

Comment: Well, yes, you are right of course. However if a user redefines `\par` like that then they probably know what they're doing ;-) But yes, your reasoning is more cautious.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik  I should have placed the `\myparcopy`-assignment right before `\noblablabla`, not into the preamble. I don't know what I was thinking there. In any case I would redefine `\par` only in ways where the last thing carried out is `\endgraf`. ;-)